# Deriving macroscopic electromagnetic field energy density from microscopic field energy density

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, maxwell-equations

J.D.Jackson in his book classical electrodynamics derives macroscopic maxwell's equations by averaging microscopic maxwell's equations ,I wonder if something similar could be done to get the macroscopic energy density from the microscopic one.
In the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.3383 ,the author suggests that we take the electromagnetic energy equation as a postulate in the macroscopic domain, my question is ,Can we by some suitable averaging technique derive this postulate from the corresponding microscopic energy density equation,just like how we can derive macroscopic maxwell's equations from averaging microscopic maxwell's equations*

- :
  https://doi.org/10.1119/1.1976000(derivation of macroscopic maxwell's equations by Rusakoff)

Answer (score 0):

Maxwell's equations are linear in sources and fields, thus mathematically, the averaging procedure is trivial.

This averaging does not necessarily produce the actual macroscopic fields (that is the hard part to prove, as the result depends on the method of averaging, and if the averaging is done with unsuitable kernel function, the result may preserve all the information about the microscopic field in a hidden way), but it does remove high-frequency Fourier components from the field.

Thus the Poynting energy and energy flux density in the microscopic theory do take into account (possibly very large) contribution due to high-frequency Fourier components of the field, while the same Poynting formulae, for the averaged fields, do not.

The Poynting energy density is a quadratic function of fields, and energy flux density is product of electric and magnetic field. Square (or product of two) of averaged fields is not, in general, similar in value or Fourier spectral characteristics, to average of the square (or product of two) of microscopic fields.

Thus it is unlikely one can obtain correctly macroscopic EM energy density from the microscopic EM energy via averaging. Instead, one has to decide at what level, microscopic or macroscopic, the Poynting expressions are valid expressions for EM energy, or if the Poynting expressions are valid at all. There are good reasons to limit the interpretation of the Poynting expressions as energy expressions only to macroscopic theory with regular charge and current distributions (those that are not delta-like, like point or line charge/current). In microscopic theory, delta-like distributions are useful, such as point charged particle, and in that context equations and their mathematics does not allow us interpreting the Poynting theorem as a law of local conservation of energy. E.g. in theory of point charged particles due to Frenkel, one has to use different energy expressions which give similar values as the Poynting expressions do only in case of many charged particles moving in a correlated way (thus creating out of set of delta distributions, after averaging, finite charge and current distributions in space).

Comment: 1) So as far as i have understood, the poynting theorem is only valid in the macroscopic case and to analyze microscopic energy we need something different ,may i know how this would look like?  2) Is there some way that we can bring the poynting theorem ,from this microscopic energy expression? this is my first exposure to classical electromagnetism so please don't mind if my questions are a bit stupid : )

Comment: The wikipedia says, "The Poynting vector in a macroscopic medium can be defined self-consistently with microscopic theory, in such a way that the spatially averaged microscopic Poynting vector is exactly predicted by a macroscopic formalism. This result is strictly valid in the limit of low-loss and allows for the unambiguous identification of the Poynting vector form in macroscopic electrodynamics"  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting%27s_theorem#cite_note-Poynting_first_principles-5 , so is it actually possible to do that and what would microscopic poyning vector look like?

Comment: You need some theory of microscopic charge and current distribution. One can use the same Maxwell equations as one has in macroscopic theory in vacuum, assuming $\rho,\mathbf j$ are not too singular densities capturing the microscopic variations in space. Then one can derive the Poynting theorem and its energy interpretation in the microscopic theory the same way as in the macroscopic theory, just $\mathbf E, \mathbf B,\rho,\mathbf j$ refer to microscopic functions capturing those microscopic variations.

Comment: Or one can analyze point particle theories a la Frenkel, which do not allow interpreting $\mathbf j\cdot \mathbf E$ as work on the charged particle per unit volume and time, and thus the Poynting theorem cannot be interpreted in terms of energy - the terms are too singular.

Comment: I did not read those referred papers, so I don't know what they're after - the fact the Poynting vector can be defined in macroscopic theory is usually taken for granted, since the fields are not too singular. Perhaps they mean this vector correctly accounts for spatial average of microscopic energy flow, which is true in some cases, and not true in some other (point charged particles moving in random, uncorrelated way).